# Linked List access violation

Tags: c++, linked-list, access-violation

I get this error during execution.

You see I had a free(temp) before the 
    cout<< 
statements.I removed them.I thought it was because of bad dereferencing turns out its something more to it.

This is my program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

node* head=NULL;
node* current=NULL;

void insert_node()
{
    int num=0;
    cout<<"\nEnter the value of the node to insert\n:";

    cin>>num;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(*head));
        //current=(node*)malloc(sizeof(*current));
        head->data=num;
        head->next=NULL;
        current=head;
        cout<<"Created list\n";

    }
    else
    {
        node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(*temp));
        temp->data=num;
        temp->next=NULL;
        current->next=temp;
        current=temp;
        cout<<"Added element\n";
        free(temp);
        cout<<"dereferenced element\n";

    }
}

void delete_node()
{

    if(head!=NULL && head->next==NULL  )//only one node
    {

        current=head=NULL;
        cout<<"Deleted Head\n";
    }
    else if(head!=NULL && head->next!=NULL)//>= 2 nodes
    {
       node* temp;
       //temp=NULL;
       temp=head;
       while(temp->next!=current)
       {
           temp=temp->next;
       }
       temp->next=NULL;
       current=temp;
       cout<<"Deleted last element\n";
      // free(temp);
       cout<<"Dereferenced temp\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"delete was not performed";
    }
}

void list_linked_list()
{
    node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(* temp));

    temp=head;

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {

        cout<<temp->data<<"->";
        temp=temp->next;

    }
    cout<<"displayed list\n";
    //free(temp);
    cout<<"dereferenced temp";
}

void search_node()
{
    cout<<"\nenter a number to search";
    int search=0,found=0;
    cin>>search;

    node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(* temp));
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data==search)
            found=1;
    }
    if(found==1)
        cout<<"found\n";
    else
    cout<<"not found\n";
    //free(temp);
    cout<<"dereferenced temp";
}


void main()
{

    int n=0;
    k:
    cout<<"Linked List operations: \n1. insert \n2. delete \n3. search\n 4. view List \n5. Exit";
    cin>>n;

    switch(n)
    {
    case 1: insert_node();break;

    case 2: delete_node();break;

    case 3: search_node();break;

    case 4: list_linked_list();break;
    case 5: exit(0);break;
    default: cout<<" Please enter valid number between 1 and 5";
            break;

    }
    goto k;
}
```

I dont think i misunderstood linked list concept.
Im pretty clear on it.I think there a mistake with the pointer.

Thank you.

EDIT: NEW CODE:

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head=NULL;
struct node* current=NULL;





void insert_node()
{
    int num=0;
    cout<<"\nEnter the value of the node to insert\n:";

    cin>>num;

    if(head==NULL)
    {

        head->data=num;
        head->next=NULL;
        current=head;
        cout<<"Created list\n";

    }
    else
    {
        struct node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data=num;
        temp->next=NULL;
        current->next=temp;
        current=temp;
        cout<<"Added element\n";
        cout<<"dereferenced element\n";

    }


}

void delete_node()
{

    if(head!=NULL && head->next==NULL  )//only one node
    {

        current=head=NULL;   //Am I supposed to do anything else here??
        cout<<"Deleted Head\n";
    }
    else
    if(head!=NULL && head->next!=NULL)//>= 2 nodes
    {
       struct node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));;
       //temp=NULL;
       temp=head;
       while(temp->next!=current)
       {
           temp=temp->next;
       }
       temp->next=NULL;
       current=temp;
       cout<<"Deleted last element\n";
      free(temp->next);
       cout<<"Dereferenced temp\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"delete was not performed";
    }


}

void list_linked_list()
{
    node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    temp=head;

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {

        cout<<temp->data<<"->";
        temp=temp->next;

    }
    cout<<"displayed list\n";
    //free(temp);              //should I free temp?
    cout<<"dereferenced temp";
}

void search_node()
{
    cout<<"\nenter a number to search";
    int search=0,found=0;
    cin>>search;

    node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data==search)
            found=1;
        else
            temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(found==1)
        cout<<"found\n";
    else
    cout<<"not found\n";
    free(temp);          //shoudl I free temp?
    cout<<"dereferenced temp";
}
```

Comment: You need to free the nodes when you delete a node. Not when you insert a node.

Comment: Don't use `free(temp)` in `insert_node()`. It changes the memory location pointed by current as unaccessible.

Comment: Why the C tag? This is C++ code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

1. You are `free()`ing a node in your insert function which is not what you want. So remove the line `free(temp)` from your insert function.
2. You *do* want to free the node when you delete an element from your linked list. So uncomment the line: `free(temp);`. But this is not the correct `current` node that you want to free(). Here `temp` is your new `current` whereas you want to free() your old `current` which `temp->next`. So your free() statement should be: `free(temp->next);` in `delete_node()` function (Not `free(temp);` ).
3. Return value of main should an `int`.
4. If you are using C++ there are better ways to implement linked lists. You may want to use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`. Use C++ headers instead of C headers.
5. If you do use C, then [don't cast the value returned by `malloc` in C.](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)
6. You are using `goto` as a replacement for a loop which is unnecessary when you can simply use `for(;;) { }` or `while(1) { }`.

Comment: Congrats for 20K RP!! :)

Comment: I did change every thing you mentioned. Now when I insert an element it says access violation or it just gets stuck

Comment: @RamapriyaSridharan I am not sure if you did exactly what I mentioned. After modifying your code works fine as shown here: http://codepad.org/WKjUquaH

Comment: Thank you! So ive got my pointer concepts wrong.I need to ask.When exactly do you use malloc?I dint use it for the pointer current.but ive initialized head with current globally so why dynamically allocate m/y for head?

Comment: @RamapriyaSridharan 1. `Should I free temp?` No, you don't call `free()` anywhere other than `delete_node()` function. 2. `//Am I supposed to do anything else here??` Yes, you do need to `free()` that node (only one node case) *before* setting it to NULL. i.e. `free(current); head=current=NULL;`

Comment: @RamapriyaSridharan That's a lot of questions ;) You need to study a good book on C and pointers in particular. `head` is just a pointer and it doesn't point to any valid memory where it can store the struct data. Hence, you need to use malloc to allocate memory.

Answer (score 3):

In insert function's else part you free new node just after adding it in Linked List that causes Undefined behaviour at runtime:

```
  else
    {
        node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(*temp));
        temp->data=num;
        temp->next=NULL;
        current->next=temp;
        current=temp;
        cout<<"Added element\n";
        free(temp);    <------"Bug"
        cout<<"dereferenced element\n";    
    }
```

Note: You can't access a node for which memory is deallocated (`free()`),  doing this is an illegal operation. You should free memory for node when you are done with the program (and don't need access that memory again).

Comment: thank you. I changed this mistake I am still getting access violation error.

Comment: @RamapriyaSridharan Append new code in your question or raise a new question.